# Laravel: check file existence without extension

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I'm saving files in server only with a md5 hashed name without extension. 
I noticed laravel `Storage::exists()` method will return true even if file does not exists. in fact laravel assume file name as a directory name. is there any way to force laravel to check file existence ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's because the way `PHP`s `file_exists` function works. Anyways, you may use something like this:

```
if(is_file('68e109f0f40ca72a15e05cc22786f8e6')) {
    // ...
}
```

Also, you may try `glob` like this:

```
$all = glob('*'); // Read everything from current directory in array
if(in_array('68e109f0f40ca72a15e05cc22786f8e6', $all)) {
    // ...
}
```

There are more ways to do this but why not use an extension?